# Calculate a function when 2D array as variables

Tags: python, arrays

I want to do a calculation through a function, which is related to kx and ky.
kx and ky are two 2D arrays.
How can I use python to do this?

Thank you!!!

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you don't just loop over x and y and set your new matrix element to (kx[x][y]/(kx[x][y]**2 + ky[x][y] ** 2)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de-facto standard package to do array math in python is `numpy`. So install the `numpy` package and then you'd do

```py
import numpy as np  ## Pretty much everyone imports numpy as np, so might as well.


def my_function(kx, ky):
    return kx / (kx**2 + ky**2)

kx = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
ky = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]) # Well we could also just have said ky = kx.T for the transpose, I guess.

output = my_function(kx, ky)
```

Note that math operations on numpy arrays are typically applied element-wise, so `kx**2` just squares each element of `kx` individually, which is what you want here. For matrix-multiplication type squaring you'd do something like `kx.dot(kx)`.

I assume your arrays `kx` and `ky` are just random examples; otherwise, there's more efficient ways to generate them than writing them out like this.

Of course nothing is wrong with the other posted solutions that use plain python objects and for loops, but for larger arrays you can expect numpy to be much more efficient.

Comment: Actually I need more complex arrays, such like a 7X7 array. The value in each rows are the same, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].  Is there any function like np.linespace? So that I can set the start number, end number, and the space? linespace(start, stop, num)

Comment: And would it look like "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" row-wise for the first one and column-wise for the second one?

Comment: There's both  `linspace` and `arange`. In this case you probably want `arange(1, 8)`. And then there are helper functions that turn this 1d array into two 2d ones, such as `meshgrid` if I recall correctly

Comment: Understand~ Thank you very much.